# pytest mocker.patch.object's return_value uses different mock than the one I passed it

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I'm using pytest to patch the os.makedirs method for a test. In a particular test I wanted to add a side effect of an exception.

So I import the `os` object that I've imported in my script under test, patch it, and then set the side effect in my test:

```py
from infrastructure.scripts.src.server_administrator import os

def mock_makedirs(self, mocker):
    mock = MagicMock()
    mocker.patch.object(os, "makedirs", return_value=mock)
    return mock

def test_if_directory_exist_exception_is_not_raised(self, administrator, mock_makedirs):
    mock_makedirs.side_effect = Exception("Directory already exists.")

    with pytest.raises(Exception) as exception:
        administrator.initialize_server()

    assert exception.value == "Directory already exists."
```

The problem I ran into was that when the mock gets called in my script under test, the side effect no longer existed. While troubleshooting I stopped the tests in the debugger to look at the ID values for the mock I created and the mock that the patch should have set as the return value and found that they are different instances:

[image: paused in the debugger and the ids don't match]

I'm still relatively new to some of the testing tools in python, so this may be me missing something in the documentation, but shouldn't the returned mock patched in here be the mock I created?? Am I patching it wrong?

## UPDATE

I even adjusted the import style to grab `makedirs` directly to patch it:

```py
def mock_makedirs(self, mocker):
    mock = MagicMock()
    mocker.patch("infrastructure.scripts.src.server_administrator.makedirs", return_value=mock)
    return mock
```

And I still run into the same "different mocks" issue.

Answer (score 5):

:facepalm:

I was patching incorrectly. I'm considering just deleting the whole question/answer, but I figured I'd leave it here in case someone runs into the same situation.

I'm defining the patch like this:

```py
mocker.patch.object(os, "makedirs", return_value=mock)
```

Which would be a valid structure *if I was patching the result a function/method*. That is, what this patch is saying is "when you **call** the makedirs, return this.

What I actually want to do is return a mock *in place* of the method. In it's current form it makes sense that I see two different mocks because the patch logic is currently "replace makedirs with a new mock and then when that mock is called, return this other mock (the mock I made)"

What I really want is just:

```py
mocker.patch.object(os, "makedirs", mock)
```

Where my third argument (in the patch.object form) is the mock module parameter (vs the named `return_value` parameter).

In retrospect, it's pretty obvious when I think about it which is why I'm considering deleting the question, but it's an easy enough trip-up that I'm going to leave it live for now.